# Issue creating custom web app in ms access 2013

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2013

We just upgraded our MS Access to 2013 and I'd like to know why I am encountering an error message when trying to create a blank custom web app in access 2013.

ERROR:

```
"an error occured in the client while attempting to communicate with the server"
```

I find it very weird as I have tried to export a table on my Access desktop Db and it successfully created a list in sharepoint using the same sharepoint path.

I provided the same sharepoint path when creating the new custom web app, anyone encounters the same issue? Our sharepoint is 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using an on premise SharePoint setup within your organization, correct? And your SharePoint Server is SharePoint 2010, correct? If that is indeed correct, you can't create or edit Access 2013 web apps on that server. In order to create and edit Access 2013 style web apps, you need several elements: Access 2013, a SharePoint Server running SharePoint 2013 (not 2010), the appropriate licenses for Access Services (the 2013 service that can come bundled with SharePoint 2013), and SQL Server 2012 or higher.
If you are using Office 365 to host your Access web apps, most of the existing plans include Access Services where you can create and edit Access web apps.